# Modify existing jQuery table sort+filter functions (child rows)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok so I have this jQuery table function (https://jsfiddle.net/51Le6o06/7/) which works perfectly with multiple tables on the same page.

I want to modify the table and functions (new fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/51Le6o06/16/) so that each row (.product-data-row) carries an information row (.product-information-row) [child row] as you can see in this fiddle.

```
<tr class="product-data-row">
              <td>data</td>
              <td>data</td>
              <td>data</td>
              <td><span class="handsetcost">£364.00 upfront</span>
                  <br><span class="amount">£10.10 per month</span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="product-information-row">
              <td colspan="100%">£364.00 upfront<br>£10.10 per month</td>
          </tr>
```

Each (.product-data-row) now has a (.product-information-row) directly under it which carries information about (.product-data-row) for now in the example above it just contains duplicate information.

Carrying over the existing jQuery function/s from the earlier table/s functions the on page load function should - sort the table rows on page load by searching for the class (.amount) then rearranging the rows in ascending order so the cheapest deal (per month) is first. Which is no longer working.

There is also a filter that filters the table rows (carried over from previous table) by showing rows with class (.free) only - this is also wrong because I would like the information rows to be shown alongside the rows containing (.free).

Each (.product-information-row) is specific to it's (.product-data-row) directly above. How can I modify the jQuery to accommodate for this. And make the table function as it's predecessor does with the extra information row.

What i'm trying to do here is have hidden data for a table row which will eventually be displayed upon clicking the table row and slide downwards eventually but I can't seem to make it work sort of a child row which DataTables uses, if anyone has any alternative methods of doing this or ideas please let me know in the comments.

**jQuery from predecessor (Needs Modifying to Work)**

```
    jQuery.fn.extend({
        sortPaging: function() {
            return this.each(function() {
                var container = $(this);
                var dataRows = [];

                /**
                 * Create an array of all rows with its value (this assumes that the amount is always a number.
                 * You should add error checking!!
                 * Also assumes that all rows are data rows, and that there are no header rows. Adjust selector appropriately.
                 */
                container.find('.internalActivities > tbody > tr').each(function(i, j) {
                    dataRows.push({
                        'amount': parseFloat($(this).find('.amount').text().replace(/£/, "")),
                        'row': $(this)
                    });
                })

                //Sort the data smallest to largest
                dataRows.sort(function(a, b) {
                    return a.amount - b.amount;
                });

                //Remove existing table rows.  This assumes that everything should be deleted, adjust selector if needed :).
                container.find('.internalActivities > tbody').empty();

                //Add rows back to table in the correct order.
                dataRows.forEach(function(ele) {
                    container.find('.internalActivities > tbody').append(ele.row);
                })


                var trs = container.find(".internalActivities tbody tr");
                var btnMore = container.find(".seeMoreRecords");
                var btnLess = container.find(".seeLessRecords");
                var trsLength = trs.length;
                var currentIndex = 4,
                    page = 4;

                trs.hide();
                trs.slice(0, currentIndex).show();
                checkButton();

                btnMore.click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    trs.slice(currentIndex, currentIndex + page).show();
                    currentIndex += page;
                    checkButton();
                });

                btnLess.click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    trs.slice(currentIndex - page, currentIndex).hide();
                    currentIndex -= page;
                    checkButton();
                });

                function checkButton() {
                    var currentLength = trs.filter("tr:visible").length;

                    if (currentLength >= trsLength) {
                        btnMore.hide();
                    } else {
                        btnMore.show();
                    }

                    if (trsLength > page && currentLength > page) {
                        btnLess.show();
                    } else {
                        btnLess.hide();
                    }

                }
                container.find('.filter-free').change(function() {
                    var $all = container.find(".internalActivities tbody tr").hide();
                    trs = this.checked ? $all.has('.free') : $all;
                    trsLength = trs.length;
                    trs.slice(0, page).show();
                    currentIndex = page;
                });
                container.find('.filter-free').click(function() {
                    container.find('.seeLessRecords').hide();
                });
            })
        }
    });

    $('.sort_paging').sortPaging();
```

**HTML**

```
    <h1>Table sorting on page load with paging</h1>

    <div class="sort_paging">

        <p>
            <input type="checkbox" class="filter-free" /> Free Handset
        </p>

        <table class="internalActivities">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>head1</th>
                    <th>head2</th>
                    <th>head3</th>
                    <th>head4</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                  <tr class="product-data-row">
                      <td>data</td>
                      <td>data</td>
                      <td>data</td>
                      <td><span class="handsetcost">£364.00 upfront</span>
                          <br><span class="amount">£10.10 per month</span></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="product-information-row">
                      <td colspan="100%">£364.00 upfront<br>£10.10 per month</td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr class="product-data-row">
                      <td>data</td>
                      <td>data</td>
                      <td>data</td>
                      <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                          <br><span class="amount">£40.40 per month</span></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="product-information-row">
                      <td colspan="100%">No upfront cost
                          <br>£40.40 per month</td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr class="product-data-row">
                      <td>data</td>
                      <td>data</td>
                      <td>data</td>
                      <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                          <br><span class="amount">£30.30 per month</span></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="product-information-row">
                      <td colspan="100%">No upfront cost
                          <br>£30.30 per month</td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr class="product-data-row">
                      <td>data</td>
                      <td>data</td>
                      <td>data</td>
                      <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                          <br><span class="amount">£16.04 per month</span></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="product-information-row">
                      <td colspan="100%">No upfront cost
                          <br>£16.04 per month</td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr class="product-data-row">
                      <td>data</td>
                      <td>data</td>
                      <td>data</td>
                      <td><span class="handsetcost">£134.00 upfront</span>
                          <br><span class="amount">£12.19 per month</span></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="product-information-row">
                      <td colspan="100%">£134.00 upfront
                          <br>£12.19 per month</td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr class="product-data-row">
                      <td>data</td>
                      <td>data</td>
                      <td>data</td>
                      <td><span class="handsetcost">£120.00 upfront</span>
                          <br><span class="amount">£14.22 per month</span></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="product-information-row">
                      <td colspan="100%">£120.00 upfront
                          <br>£14.22 per month</td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr class="product-data-row">
                      <td>data</td>
                      <td>data</td>
                      <td>data</td>
                      <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                          <br><span class="amount">£50.22 per month</span></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="product-information-row">
                      <td colspan="100%">No upfront cost
                          <br>£50.22 per month</td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr class="product-data-row">
                      <td>data</td>
                      <td>data</td>
                      <td>data</td>
                      <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                          <br><span class="amount">£10.33 per month</span></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="product-information-row">
                      <td colspan="100%">No upfront cost
                          <br>£10.33 per month</td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr class="product-data-row">
                      <td>data</td>
                      <td>data</td>
                      <td>data</td>
                      <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                          <br><span class="amount">£40.45 per month</span></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="product-information-row">
                      <td colspan="100%">No upfront cost
                          <br>£40.45 per month</td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr class="product-data-row">
                      <td>data</td>
                      <td>data</td>
                      <td>data</td>
                      <td><span class="handsetcost">£200.00 upfront</span>
                          <br><span class="amount">£30.84 per month</span></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="product-information-row">
                      <td colspan="100%">£200.00 upfront
                          <br>£30.84 per month</td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr class="product-data-row">
                      <td>data</td>
                      <td>data</td>
                      <td>data</td>
                      <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                          <br><span class="amount">£16.14 per month</span></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="product-information-row">
                      <td colspan="100%">No upfront cost
                          <br>£16.14 per month</td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr class="product-data-row">
                      <td>data</td>
                      <td>data</td>
                      <td>data</td>
                      <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                          <br><span class="amount">£12.10 per month</span></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="product-information-row">
                      <td colspan="100%">No upfront cost
                          <br>£12.10 per month</td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr class="product-data-row">
                      <td>data</td>
                      <td>data</td>
                      <td>data</td>
                      <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                          <br><span class="amount">£14.02 per month</span></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="product-information-row">
                      <td colspan="100%">No upfront cost
                          <br>£14.02 per month</td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr class="product-data-row">
                      <td>data</td>
                      <td>data</td>
                      <td>data</td>
                      <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                          <br><span class="amount">£50.88 per month</span></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="product-information-row">
                      <td colspan="100%">No upfront cost
                          <br>£50.88 per month</td>
                  </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <input type="button" class="seeMoreRecords" value="More">
        <input type="button" class="seeLessRecords" value="Less">

    </div>

    <h2>Second table below</h2>

    <div class="sort_paging">

        <p>
            <input type="checkbox" class="filter-free" /> Free Handset
        </p>

        <table class="internalActivities">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>head1</th>
                    <th>head2</th>
                    <th>head3</th>
                    <th>head4</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                <tr class="product-data-row">
                    <td>data</td>
                    <td>data</td>
                    <td>data</td>
                    <td><span class="handsetcost">£364.00 upfront</span>
                        <br><span class="amount">£10.10 per month</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="product-information-row">
                    <td colspan="100%">£364.00 upfront<br>£10.10 per month</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="product-data-row">
                    <td>data</td>
                    <td>data</td>
                    <td>data</td>
                    <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                        <br><span class="amount">£40.40 per month</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="product-information-row">
                    <td colspan="100%">No upfront cost
                        <br>£40.40 per month</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="product-data-row">
                    <td>data</td>
                    <td>data</td>
                    <td>data</td>
                    <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                        <br><span class="amount">£30.30 per month</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="product-information-row">
                    <td colspan="100%">No upfront cost
                        <br>£30.30 per month</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="product-data-row">
                    <td>data</td>
                    <td>data</td>
                    <td>data</td>
                    <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                        <br><span class="amount">£16.04 per month</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="product-information-row">
                    <td colspan="100%">No upfront cost
                        <br>£16.04 per month</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="product-data-row">
                    <td>data</td>
                    <td>data</td>
                    <td>data</td>
                    <td><span class="handsetcost">£134.00 upfront</span>
                        <br><span class="amount">£12.19 per month</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="product-information-row">
                    <td colspan="100%">£134.00 upfront
                        <br>£12.19 per month</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="product-data-row">
                    <td>data</td>
                    <td>data</td>
                    <td>data</td>
                    <td><span class="handsetcost">£120.00 upfront</span>
                        <br><span class="amount">£14.22 per month</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="product-information-row">
                    <td colspan="100%">£120.00 upfront
                        <br>£14.22 per month</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="product-data-row">
                    <td>data</td>
                    <td>data</td>
                    <td>data</td>
                    <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                        <br><span class="amount">£50.22 per month</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="product-information-row">
                    <td colspan="100%">No upfront cost
                        <br>£50.22 per month</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="product-data-row">
                    <td>data</td>
                    <td>data</td>
                    <td>data</td>
                    <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                        <br><span class="amount">£10.33 per month</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="product-information-row">
                    <td colspan="100%">No upfront cost
                        <br>£10.33 per month</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="product-data-row">
                    <td>data</td>
                    <td>data</td>
                    <td>data</td>
                    <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                        <br><span class="amount">£40.45 per month</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="product-information-row">
                    <td colspan="100%">No upfront cost
                        <br>£40.45 per month</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="product-data-row">
                    <td>data</td>
                    <td>data</td>
                    <td>data</td>
                    <td><span class="handsetcost">£200.00 upfront</span>
                        <br><span class="amount">£30.84 per month</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="product-information-row">
                    <td colspan="100%">£200.00 upfront
                        <br>£30.84 per month</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="product-data-row">
                    <td>data</td>
                    <td>data</td>
                    <td>data</td>
                    <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                        <br><span class="amount">£16.14 per month</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="product-information-row">
                    <td colspan="100%">No upfront cost
                        <br>£16.14 per month</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="product-data-row">
                    <td>data</td>
                    <td>data</td>
                    <td>data</td>
                    <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                        <br><span class="amount">£12.10 per month</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="product-information-row">
                    <td colspan="100%">No upfront cost
                        <br>£12.10 per month</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="product-data-row">
                    <td>data</td>
                    <td>data</td>
                    <td>data</td>
                    <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                        <br><span class="amount">£14.02 per month</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="product-information-row">
                    <td colspan="100%">No upfront cost
                        <br>£14.02 per month</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="product-data-row">
                    <td>data</td>
                    <td>data</td>
                    <td>data</td>
                    <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                        <br><span class="amount">£50.88 per month</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="product-information-row">
                    <td colspan="100%">No upfront cost
                        <br>£50.88 per month</td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>

        <input type="button" class="seeMoreRecords" value="More">
        <input type="button" class="seeLessRecords" value="Less">

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lot of open issues in your code, so quick fix took more than hour. Try to go through the code below, hope you will get some ideas (and please next time try to be more accurate with questions, maybe divide it into several questions in order to get quick and concise answers):

```js
jQuery.fn.sortPaging = function(options) {
    var defaults = {
        pageRows: 2
    };
    var settings = $.extend(true, defaults, options);
    return this.each(function() {
        
  var container = $(this);
  var tableBody = container.find('.internalActivities > tbody');
  var dataRows = [];
  var currentPage = 1;
  var maxPages = 1;
  var buttonMore = container.find('.seeMoreRecords');
  var buttonLess = container.find('.seeLessRecords');
  var buttonFree = container.find('.filter-free');
  var tableRows = [];
  var maxFree = 0;
  var filterFree = buttonFree.is(':checked');
  function displayRows() {
   tableBody.empty();
   var displayed = 0;
   $.each(dataRows, function(i, ele) {
    if( !filterFree || (filterFree && ele.isFree) ) {
     tableBody.append(ele.thisRow).append(ele.nextRow);
     displayed++;
     if( displayed >= currentPage*settings.pageRows ) {
      return false;
     };
    };
   });
   tableBody.find('.product-data-row').on('click', function(e){
    $(this).next().toggle();
   });
  };
  function checkButtons() {
   buttonLess.toggleClass('element_invisible', currentPage<=1);
   buttonMore.toggleClass('element_invisible', filterFree ? currentPage>=maxFreePages : currentPage>=maxPages);
  };
  function showMore() {
   currentPage++;
   displayRows();
   checkButtons();
  };
  function showLess() {
   currentPage--;
   displayRows();
   checkButtons();
  };
  function changedFree() {
   filterFree = buttonFree.is(':checked');
   if( filterFree && currentPage>maxFreePages ) {
    currentPage=maxFreePages;
   };
   displayRows();
   checkButtons();
  };
  
        tableBody.find('.product-data-row').each(function(i, j) {
            var thisRow = $(this);
            var nextRow = thisRow.next();
   var amount = parseFloat(thisRow.find('.amount').text().replace(/£/, ''));
   var isFree = thisRow.find('.free').length;
   maxFree += isFree;
            dataRows.push({
                amount: amount,
                thisRow: thisRow,
                nextRow: nextRow,
    isFree: isFree
            });
        })

        dataRows.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a.amount - b.amount;
        });
  maxPages = Math.ceil(dataRows.length/settings.pageRows);
  maxFreePages = Math.ceil(maxFree/settings.pageRows);

        tableRows = tableBody.find("tr");

        buttonMore.on('click', showMore);
  buttonLess.on('click', showLess);
        buttonFree.on('change', changedFree);
  
  displayRows();
  checkButtons();
        
    })

};

$('.sort_paging').sortPaging();
```

```css
table,
tr,
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 8px;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 18px;
}
.element_invisible {
 display: none;
}
.product-information-row {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Table sorting on page load with paging</h1>

<div class="sort_paging">

    <p>
        <input type="checkbox" class="filter-free" /> Free Handset
    </p>

    <table class="internalActivities">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>head1</th>
                <th>head2</th>
                <th>head3</th>
                <th>head4</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="handsetcost">£364.00 upfront</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£10.10 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%">£364.00 upfront
                    <br>£10.10 per month</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£40.40 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%">No upfront cost
                    <br>£40.40 per month</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£30.30 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%">No upfront cost
                    <br>£30.30 per month</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£16.04 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%">No upfront cost
                    <br>£16.04 per month</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="handsetcost">£134.00 upfront</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£12.19 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%">£134.00 upfront
                    <br>£12.19 per month</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="handsetcost">£120.00 upfront</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£14.22 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%">£120.00 upfront
                    <br>£14.22 per month</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£50.22 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%">No upfront cost
                    <br>£50.22 per month</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£10.33 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%">No upfront cost
                    <br>£10.33 per month</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£40.45 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%">No upfront cost
                    <br>£40.45 per month</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="handsetcost">£200.00 upfront</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£30.84 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%">£200.00 upfront
                    <br>£30.84 per month</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£16.14 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%">No upfront cost
                    <br>£16.14 per month</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£12.10 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%">No upfront cost
                    <br>£12.10 per month</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£14.02 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%">No upfront cost
                    <br>£14.02 per month</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£50.88 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%">No upfront cost
                    <br>£50.88 per month</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <input type="button" class="seeMoreRecords" value="More">
    <input type="button" class="seeLessRecords" value="Less">

</div>

<h2>Second table below</h2>

<div class="sort_paging">

    <p>
        <input type="checkbox" class="filter-free" /> Free Handset
    </p>

    <table class="internalActivities">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>head1</th>
                <th>head2</th>
                <th>head3</th>
                <th>head4</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="handsetcost">£364.00 upfront</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£10.10 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%">£364.00 upfront
                    <br>£10.10 per month</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£40.40 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%">No upfront cost
                    <br>£40.40 per month</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£30.30 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%">No upfront cost
                    <br>£30.30 per month</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£16.04 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%">No upfront cost
                    <br>£16.04 per month</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="handsetcost">£134.00 upfront</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£12.19 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%">£134.00 upfront
                    <br>£12.19 per month</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="handsetcost">£120.00 upfront</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£14.22 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%">£120.00 upfront
                    <br>£14.22 per month</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£50.22 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%">No upfront cost
                    <br>£50.22 per month</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£10.33 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%">No upfront cost
                    <br>£10.33 per month</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£40.45 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%">No upfront cost
                    <br>£40.45 per month</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="handsetcost">£200.00 upfront</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£30.84 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%">£200.00 upfront
                    <br>£30.84 per month</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£16.14 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%">No upfront cost
                    <br>£16.14 per month</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£12.10 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%">No upfront cost
                    <br>£12.10 per month</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£14.02 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%">No upfront cost
                    <br>£14.02 per month</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="product-data-row">
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£50.88 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="product-information-row">
                <td colspan="100%">No upfront cost
                    <br>£50.88 per month</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>

    <input type="button" class="seeMoreRecords" value="More">
    <input type="button" class="seeLessRecords" value="Less">

</div>
```

Also on [updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/51Le6o06/17/);

Comment: awesome I did come up with a solution myself but yours is far better - thanks, I do have one more question whilst on this topic as you have coded this answer I think you will know the best way to implement it, is it possible to add a second filter next to the free handset checkbox filter for each table? which is only shown if the filter is available ( or if data is present to be filtered by)

Comment: (on the right) i'd like a dropdown box filter that filters the rows based on data that is inside the product-information-row to filter which deals contain a free gift, for example if child row 2,5,8 of table one contain a free gift "Free TV" `<p class="information">Free TV</p>` and child row 1 contains "£25 Cashback  `<p class="information">£25 cashback</p>` have the dropdown box pre populate this data then available to filter the table by it?

Comment: The way you started to build these tables is not the way I would do it. Since you can implement one filter, guess you can implement 10 more, but you should think about that before you created the code. So, before writing any code you should put on paper what you need, than think of easiest way to create and manage your widget. Also, one important thing is: do not invent something that was already invented - and in your case, since you work with tabular data, check existing plugins as [datatables](https://www.datatables.net/) and [others](http://www.sitepoint.com/30-amazing-jquery-tables/).

Comment: I've only been messing with jQuery for a couple weeks I had thought about using datatables but I needed to work with existing HTML and I couldn't find any examples of paging the way my tables do with datatables and because this is just for the mobile side of my website I thought it would be easier to just make it custom

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36851603/add-filter-to-existing-table-functions-jquery-javascript